# collectfiles failes for pipeline / yUglify: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: django, django-pipeline, collectstatic

I've been trying to get django-pipeline to work to combine and minify my css and js assets. I don't seem to be able to sort the following issue out. When I run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I get an error:

```
pipeline.exceptions.CompressorError: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Do I maybe need to install some additional packages? If so, how?

My settings for django-pipeline:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'testme': {
        'source_filenames': {
            'static/surveys/css/main.css',
        },
        'output_filename': 'css/testme.css',
    },
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'testmejs': {
        'source_filenames': {
            'surveys/js/gklib.js',
        },
        'output_filename': 'surveys/js/testmejs.css',
    },
}

PIPELINE_ENABLED = True
```

This is the complete output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\storage.py", line 36, in post_process
    packager.pack_javascripts(package)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\packager.py", line 112, in pack_javascripts
    return self.pack(package, self.compressor.compress_js, js_compressed, templates=package.templates, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\packager.py", line 106, in pack
    content = compress(paths, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\compressors\__init__.py", line 67, in compress_js
    js = getattr(compressor(verbose=self.verbose), 'compress_js')(js)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\compressors\yuglify.py", line 13, in compress_js
    return self.compress_common(js, 'js', settings.PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_JS_ARGUMENTS)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\compressors\yuglify.py", line 10, in compress_common
    return self.execute_command(command, content)
  File "d:\Development\django\TopDish\env_mrg_tacx_laptop\lib\site-packages\pipeline\compressors\__init__.py", line 240, in execute_command
    raise CompressorError(stderr)
pipeline.exceptions.CompressorError: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

UPDATE

I've tried it again using another compressor:

```
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.csstidy.CSSTidyCompressor'
```

This gives the exact same result, what could I be doing wrong?

UPDATE 2

If I set the compressors to None everything works, i.e. the files get combined and placed in the static files folder. They are also served correctly.

```
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = None
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = None
```

So it must be something either in accessing or using the compressors. I'm running on Windows.

UPDATE 3

I've added some print() commands to **init**.py in /site-packages/pipeline/compressors/

```
class SubProcessCompressor(CompressorBase):
    def execute_command(self, command, content):
        import subprocess
        print("Command: " + command)
```

The command is: /usr/bin/env/ yuglify --type=css --terminal 
Which can (probably?) never work on Windows.

I've then tried to deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I get an error then as well:

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR: [Instance: i-75dc5e91 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command 01_collectstatic failed.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

I know it's possible to manually set the location of the compressors bin, but where to set it for Elastic Beanstalk?

Any suggestions how to sort this out?

Comment: Note that arguments are now in a PIPELINE object, so 
```PIPELINE = {
   ...
    'CSS_COMPRESSOR': None,
    'JS_COMPRESSOR': None,
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by adding commands to the .ebextensions/app.config file:

```
# these commands run before the application and web server are
# set up and the application version file is extracted
commands:
  01_node_install:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if node is already installed (file /usr/bin/node exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/node ] && echo "node not installed"'
    # install from epel repository
    # flag -y for no-interaction installation
    command: 'yum install -y nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel'
    command: 'npm -g install yuglify'
```

Based these commands on what I found on http://qpleple.com/install-nodejs-on-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: it is better to split the `yum install -y nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel` and `npm -g install yuglify` into 2 seperate commands, eg. `01_node_install` and `02_yuglify_install`.